# Replace instances of a pattern in a file

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, python-re

I am trying to open a file, use `re` to find a pattern, and then pass each instance of the pattern to a function for processing, then replace each instance of the pattern in a file.  I have a working function.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

def replacetimestamp(replace):
    #document uses milliseconds not seconds.
    x = replace * .001
    dt_object = datetime.fromtimestamp(x)
    return dt_object
    print(dt_object)
```

All is good, so when I try to use the function in my main script, I run into problems. I am thinking that either I broke the `re` object, or that I am not writing to the file, but everything I try does not work.

Here is the rest:

```
import re
import time, datetime
import replacetimestamp
timestamp = re.compile(r'/d{13}')
for  line in open("testpython.json"):
    for timestamp in re.finditer(timestamp, line):
        timestamp.replacetimestamp()
```

Comment: python version 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub` for this.  It can take a function to replace all non-overlapping matches with a replacement based on the match.  Example:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

test_data = 'stamp 1604344808485 stamp 1604344809000'

# re.sub passes a match object (m) into this function.
# m.group(0) is the string that matched.
def replace_timestamp(m):
    stamp = int(m.group(0)) * .001
    # Replace with the string representation of the datetime object,
    # not the object itself.  Use datetime.strptime() if a different
    # format is needed.
    return str(datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp))

updated = re.sub(r'\d{13}',replace_timestamp,test_data)
print(updated)
```

Output:

```
stamp 2020-11-02 11:20:08.485000 stamp 2020-11-02 11:20:09
```

For your case something like the following should work (untested):

```
with open('testpython.json') as infile, open('outpython.json','w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = re.sub(r'\d{13}',replace_timestamp,line)
        outfile.write(line)
```